# In a very large MySQL analytics table - should I index the timestamp?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I'm looking to improve the speed of queries on a very large MySQL analytics table that I have. This table is tracking playercount on gameservers and the structure looks as so:

```
`server_tracker` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `port` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `players` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `map` varchar(28) NOT NULL,
  `portjoin` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_tracking_ip_port` (`ip`,`port`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=310729056 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED |
```

This table is inserted into very frequently, with 10k+ servers being tracked 10+ times an hour. However, every hour the data is taken and averaged out, and put into an "averaged" table with basically the same structure.

Currently I have the IP/port setup as key. However - sometimes it can be a tad slow when doing that hourly averaging - so I am curious if it would be worth putting an index on the timestamp, which is frequently used to select data from a certain timeframe like so:

```
    SELECT  `players`
    FROM  `server_tracker`
    WHERE  `ip` = x
      AND  `port` = x
      AND  `date` > NOW()
      AND  `date` < NOW() + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE
    ORDER BY  `id` DESC
```

This is the only type of query ran on this table. The table is only used for fetching the playercount from gameservers within a specific timeframe. The data is never updated or changed.

However, I am a bit new to all of this - and I am not sure if putting an index on the timestamp would do much of anything. Just looking for some friendly advice.

Results of `EXPLAIN SELECT players FROM server_tracker WHERE ip = x AND port = x AND date > NOW() AND date < NOW() + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE ORDER BY id DESC`

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref         | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | server_tracker  | ref  | idx_tracking_ip_port | idx_tracking_ip_port | 6       | const,const | 15354 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: Yes, you'll likely want indexes on anything you're using in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: it is important to know the access paths of all your queries that are bottlenecks to try to craft indexes (single column, composite, covering). Otherwise we can just give broad brush stroke replies. And if taken the wrong way, leave you worse off

Comment: @ceejayoz My question is would this increase disk space usage dramatically? Wouldn't it have to save all these dates for these millions of rows grown overtime into a file? I am not exactly sure how indexes work on the inside, since most explanations only explain why and how to use them.

Comment: @Drew What do you mean by "access path"? As in, the type of queries I'll be running on this table? The only type of query I am running is the select query in the OP. Selecting the playercount by looking up the IP/port/date. This data is never updated or changed - it does get deleted every so often though.

Comment: correct. Your situation is good in so far as there is no goose chase to see what other queries ... index changes would affect.

Comment: Can you provide under [edit] the results of `show create table server_tracker`

Comment: and run `EXPLAIN SELECT players FROM server_tracker WHERE ip = x AND port = x AND date > NOW() AND date < NOW() + INTERVAL 60 MINUTE ORDER BY id DESC` and publish that too

Comment: @DizzyPain: db indexes = index at the back of a book, essentially. they tell the db which "pages" some piece of data is in. there's overhead in maintaining/building an index, which is generally vastly outweighed by the savings in not having to scan your entire table to locate something.

Comment: @Drew - I've added both to the OP. It actually turns out I setup the IP/port as keys, which makes sense since that's basically what they are (the data is always access with IP and port in the query). But the question still remains, would it help to index the date?

Comment: Bug...  Your range is one second shy of one hour.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important information in MySQL and scripts is to know the MySQL to very few exceptions, **always just ONE INDEX can be used in a query**. 
So it does not use much depending on an index ever to set a Column when all 4 are used verfelder in the where clause.

Only a combined index hilt over these fields.
The order of the fields is very important for this index can also be used for other queries.

An example:

An index on field1, field2 and field3 is used when you have the WHERE FIELD1 or FIELD1 and FIELD2 or field1, field2 and FIELD3. This index is not used if you in the WHERE FIELD2 or used FIELD3 or FIELD2 and field. 3 So always use the first field.

Too easy to find out if un like the QUERY works you can just run your query and EXPALIN and beommst directly the information whether and which index is used. If there are several lines you can as an indicator, the individual values ​​under rows muliplizieren together. The smaller this number is the better performs your query.

```
MariaDB [tmp]> EXPLAIN select * from content;
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | content | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   13 |       |
+------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]>
```

Anternativ you can check out the profiler how long the QUERY in what capacity depends and about optimizing server

An example:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use tmp
Database changed
MariaDB [tmp]> SET PROFILING=ON;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]>
MariaDB [tmp]> SELECT * FROM content;
+----+------+---------------------+--------+------+--------------+------+------+------+------+
| id | Wert | Zeitstempel         | WertID | aaa  | d            | e    | wwww | n    | ddd  |
+----+------+---------------------+--------+------+--------------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |   10 | 2001-01-01 00:00:00 |      1 | NULL |       1.5000 | NULL | NULL |    1 | NULL |
|  2 | 12.3 | 2001-01-01 00:01:00 |      2 | NULL |       2.5000 | NULL | NULL |    2 | NULL |
|  3 | 17.4 | 2001-01-01 00:02:00 |      3 | NULL |  123456.1250 | NULL | NULL |    3 | NULL |
|  4 | 10.9 | 2001-01-01 01:01:00 |      1 | NULL | 1000000.0000 | NULL | NULL |    4 | NULL |
|  5 | 15.4 | 2001-01-01 01:02:00 |      2 | NULL |         NULL | NULL | NULL |    5 | NULL |
|  6 | 20.9 | 2001-01-01 01:03:00 |      3 | NULL |         NULL | NULL | NULL |    6 | NULL |
|  7 |   22 | 2001-01-02 00:00:00 |      1 | NULL |         NULL | NULL | NULL |    7 | NULL |
|  8 | 12.3 | 2001-01-02 00:01:00 |      2 | NULL |         NULL | NULL | NULL |    8 | NULL |
|  9 | 17.4 | 2001-01-02 00:02:00 |      3 | NULL |         NULL | NULL | NULL |    
+----+------+---------------------+--------+------+--------------+------+------+------+------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]>
MariaDB [tmp]> SHOW PROFILE;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000031 |
| checking permissions | 0.000005 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000036 |
| After opening tables | 0.000004 |
| System lock          | 0.000003 |
| Table lock           | 0.000002 |
| After opening tables | 0.000005 |
| init                 | 0.000013 |
| optimizing           | 0.000006 |
| statistics           | 0.000013 |
| preparing            | 0.000010 |
| executing            | 0.000002 |
| Sending data         | 0.000073 |
| end                  | 0.000003 |
| query end            | 0.000003 |
| closing tables       | 0.000006 |
| freeing items        | 0.000003 |
| updating status      | 0.000012 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000003 |
+----------------------+----------+
19 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]>
```

Comment: I've added some new information to the OP. You said only 1 index can be used per query? I have the IP/port setup as a key - which is what the WHERE clause is using, in addition to the date. No other types of queries are really ran on this table. If you can only make use of 1 index, would it not be useful to index the date? Sorry if I misunderstood your post, your English was a tad hard to read.

Comment: Sorry, i have translate it with google :-). Create one index with all fields you are using in your query  "ALTER TABLE server_tracker ADD INDEX somename (ip, port, `date`);" then can the query use it perfect. the order of the fields in the ALTER TABLE is also importend. The where witch can reduce the result mostly must be first. a Sample: 10k rows, 5000 with port a and 5000 with port b, and 100 with ip 1. then is ip the first field in the index. so you can reduce the internal resultset vom 10k total to 100 rows after the first where ip=xx and the next reduce only must search in 100 rows